# Why are primitive roots of unity the only solution to these equations?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I was led by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94498) to the following problem:

Find $n$ complex numbers $\lambda_1\dots\lambda_n\in\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy

$$\begin{align} 
\sum_i\lambda_i & =0\\
\sum_i\lambda_i^2 & =0\\
\sum_i\lambda_i^3 & =0\\
&\vdots\\
\sum_i\lambda_i^{n-1} & =0\\
\end{align}$$

I'm pretty sure that the only solution for these equations is $\lambda_k = w \zeta^k$ where $w$ is some complex number and $\zeta$ is the primitive $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity. By "only" I mean of course that you can permute the $\lambda_i$'s because the equations are all symmetric polynomials, but that's it.

Is there a proof for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By writing the  elementary symmetric functions in terms of your power sums using [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), you get $$(X-\lambda_1)\cdots(X-\lambda_n)=X^n+(-1)^n\lambda_1\cdots \lambda_n=X^n-w^n=(X-w)(X-w\zeta)\cdots(X-w\zeta^{n-1})$$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity and $w$ is any $n$th root of $-(-1)^{n}\lambda_1\cdots \lambda_n$. The result follows at once now.

This solution also follows from the observation that the power sums are homogeneous and hence one can normalize the problem by dividing all $\lambda_i$ by some factor. Choosing the factor such that $(-1)^{n}\lambda_1\cdots \lambda_n=-1$ gives $X^n-1$.

[Thanks to [Greg Martin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16078/greg-martin) for simplifying my original answer.]

Comment: Note that your first sentence can be strengthened: not only is each $\lambda_j$ a root of $X^n = (-1)^{n+1}\lambda_1\cdots \lambda_n$, but the polynomial $(X-\lambda_1)\cdots(X-\lambda_n)$ is actually equal to the polynomial $X^n - (-1)^{n+1}\lambda_1\cdots \lambda_n$. This latter polynomial factors as $(X-w)(X-w\zeta)\cdots(X-w\zeta^{n-1})$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity and $w$ is any $n$th root of $(-1)^{n+1}\lambda_1\cdots \lambda_n$ (note this is true even if $w=0$). This immediately establishes the OP's proposition.

Comment: Do you want to just edit yours? It's an observation on what's otherwise your solution....

Comment: @GregMartin, done, thanks!